# What Windows-installer tools support Windows 7 conventions?

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-installer, nsis

Many years ago, the premier Windows installer tool was NSIS, from the makers of WinAmp. It was great because:

- It was free
- It was text-scriptable
- It had a preprocessor, (!ifdef and !ifndef)
- It was plugin-able, to add specialty features not included by NSIS out the door.

Now, NSIS fails to keep up with conventions, especially with security components of Windows 7. I saw a 3.0a1 release, but even these release notes were unreadable.

What are people using out there, to solve the problem of a Windows-installer? In particular, I'm looking for the same kinds of features listed above from NSIS, but are keeping up with Windows Vista, 7 and 8 installer standards?

Comment: The installtime experience is far more important then the development experience. #IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current alpha release has a problem with links in RTF files on the license page, other than that there are no real issues with 3.0a1 AFAIK.

The release notes are somewhat broken online because SourceForge keeps changing stuff but they are available in the help file if you install it. You can view the raw SVN release notes [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/code/HEAD/tree/NSIS/trunk/Docs/src/history.but).

2.4x added support for `RequestExecutionLevel` and 3.0 offers more control over DPI aware and the supported OS guids in the manifest, not sure what other NT6 stuff you believe are missing.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your question is false-- NSIS works fine with "security components" of Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1. I use it for Fiddler, and it's used by untold thousands of other applications from small companies to the largest enterprises.

I don't know what you mean by "unreadable"-- the 3.0 release notes are perfectly reasonable. v3 addresses the only major limitation of NSIS2, lack of Unicode support. Now that this support is present, NSIS3 looks to be a fine choice of Windows Desktop installer for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Except that NSIS isn't a Windows Installer based tool.  It lacks so many critical features.

Comment: Wordplay sure is fun, isn't it? NSIS is a tool for building Windows Installers. It's correct to note that NSIS doesn't build MSI files based around "Windows Installer technologies". The claim that it lacks "so many critical features" is opinion based and subject to extensive debate, none of which would be very useful in answering the OP's question. As you're clearly very opinionated in this topic, perhaps you'd like to propose your own answer to the question (e.g. WiX, perhaps?)

Comment: No, it's not word play.  Read the tag FAQ.  Windows Installer is a very specific technology that offers specific capabilities not provided by any other technology.

Comment: You're rather missing the point, Christopher. Rather than having a pointless debate, next time please consider productively contributing an answer. Thanks.